# ffmpeg -pattern_type glob not working in Google Colab

Tags: ffmpeg, google-colaboratory, glob

I'm trying to combine images into video using ffmpeg in a Google Colab Notebook; I'm getting errors but don't see what I'm doing wrong.

`!ffmpeg -pattern_type glob  -i 2023021522* -c:v libx264 video2.mp4`

returns: Option pattern_type not found.

`!ffmpeg -pattern_type glob  -i '2023021522*' -c:v libx264 video2.mp4` or
`!ffmpeg -pattern_type glob  -i "2023021522*" -c:v libx264 video2.mp4`

return: 2023021522*: No such file or directory

I also tried adding `from glob import glob` and just `import glob`

Answer (score 0):

`-pattern_type glob` is not required by ffmpeg - perhaps it was in a previous version because it shows up in web searches for how to use glob with ffmepg. It can simply be omitted:

!ffmpeg -i 2023021522* -c:v libx264 video2.mp4

And ffmpeg will glob the input filename.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).